# Postgres wait for transaction to finish

Tags: database, postgresql, transactions

When doing a concurrent update in postgres, I get a

> ERROR:  could not serialize access due to concurrent update

Is there a way to make the transaction wait until the other transaction has finished, rather than failing with an errror?

Here's my test case:

```
-- SESSION 1
START TRANSACTION;
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL Serializable;

SELECT pg_sleep(5); -- 5 second delay
UPDATE users SET nonce = nonce + 1 WHERE u_id = 'dude';

COMMIT;
```

and another session (session 2) happens concurrently

```
-- SESSION 2
START TRANSACTION;
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL Serializable;

UPDATE users SET nonce = nonce + 1 WHERE u_id = 'dude';

COMMIT;
```

How do I make transactions wait for the previous transaction to finish before executing. As of right now, it won't execute, it will just report the error, which leaves me managing the failure logic on my server instead. Is there something like a transaction queue I can use? Or maybe a statement that checks to see if there are other transactions going on, and then wait for it to resolve?

(NOTE: I'm using postgres and my transaction isolation is set to serializable)

**EDIT:**

I solved this problem by making a few minor modifications. **I changed the transaction isolation to Read committed, and moved the 5 second delay after the update statement.**

It's important that the delay is after the update statement, because the **database doesn't put a block on the row until it reads the update statement.**

Here is the revised test case:

```
-- SESSION 1
START TRANSACTION;
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL Read committed;

UPDATE users SET nonce = nonce + 1 WHERE u_id = 'dude';
SELECT pg_sleep(5); -- 5 second delay

COMMIT;
```

and another session (session 2) happens concurrently

```
-- SESSION 2
START TRANSACTION;
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL Read committed;

UPDATE users SET nonce = nonce + 1 WHERE u_id = 'dude';

COMMIT;
```

In this scenario, the session 2 transaction waits for the session 1 transaction to commit before committing itself.

Comment: Why would you set `autocommit = 1` inside a transaction?

Comment: If you are only updating one row at a time, I see no need to change the default transaction isolation level. What problem are you trying to avoid by doing so?

Comment: @DondiMichaelStroma I think a better description of what I want, is a way to repeat a transaction in the case that I get a concurrency error.

Comment: Well, in `Read committed` it's not the whole transaction waits for another transaction to complete, but a single statement waits for an object to be unlocked. And if you run both simultaneously I'd say that the 2nd completes first (since there is no reason for it to not to).

Comment: @BrianSmith I understand that, the question I was asking is why do you want to use the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level in the first place?

Comment: Read committed is the default isolation level, read the docs.

Comment: @zerkms You were right, I put the 5 second delay before the first transaction reads the UPDATE statement, meaning that it didn't block the UPDATE statement's row.

Answer (score 1):

You've set the `Serializable` isolation level, it means that as soon as the transaction cannot be serialized - then it will fail.

That's how it works by design.

And, no, you cannot change its behaviour.

Comment: Is there a better isolation level?

Comment: "better", meaning more relevant to my use case. My use case is to have transactions wait for the other one to finish (queue them).

Comment: @BrianSmith none of transaction isolation levels provide you the "wait for the other one to finish" facility. So, the answer for this very question would be "No".